# skipping a function if returned value is None?

Tags: python

Is there anyway to avoid a function call if function returns `None`?
I'm doing this at the moment, but it seems very inefficient calling the function twice

```
if  bool(runChecks(problems)):
    return  runChecks(problems)
```

I would rather do this in one line of code, instead of calling it twice. If it returns `True`, then it returns a string with the error.

If it returns false, then it continues with the rest of the program. The runChecks() is a function that makes sure input is viable for program. no letters or chars that I havnt programmed it for

Comment: What are you doing if it returns `False`?

Comment: what is the output of `runChecks` ?

Comment: often this is a good case for a custom Exception, which will let you break out of a whole tree of functions at once to be caught where you want the result

Comment: added edits for answers to the 1st questions. Sorry new to site struggling to reply to right comments

Answer (score 4):

Try the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions)

```py
if val:=runChecks(problems):
    return val
```

Comment: I'm struggling with understanding how the operator works, but I think this may be what I'm after, thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
value = runChecks(problems)
if value:
    return value
```